# Ant Design Menu and Menu Item Customize

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to make Menu.Item component like below but it doesn't work well...

Nav.js

```
<Menu mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={[URL]}>
  <LeftMenu />
  <RightMenu />
</Menu>
```

LeftMenu.js

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Menu.Item key="notice" {...props}>
    <Link to='/notice/board'>Notice</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="about" {...props}>
    <Link to='/about'>About Us</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="detail" {...props}>
    <Link to="/detail/room-info">Room</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="reservation" {...props}>
    <Link to='/reservation'>Reservation</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="contact" {...props}>
    <Link to='/contact/board'>Contact</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4853) in github on this topic.

You can use the menu like this

```
<Menu mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={[URL]}>
  {LeftMenu()}
  {RightMenu()}
</Menu>
```